# Can we use Euclidean metric to define distance on a topological immersion of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: manifolds, projective-space

Probably we can't. But why?

My reasoning is that any topological immersion of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (e.g. cross-cap, Roman surface) seems to intersect itself (I will find a proof or disproof of it later, but now suppose that's true), and so for a point $p$ on the intersection, among open sets defined by Euclidean metric, we can't find an (open) neighborhood of $p$. Therefore with Euclidean metric we can't make a topological immersion of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ a manifold.

Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: I mean you can find an open neighbourhood of $p$ but presumably you want it to do something. The issue here is that the two points at the self intersection would have distance $0$ from each other, but for metrics we only allow distance $0$ if they are the same point.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If we use Euclidean metric ($d(p,q) = \sqrt{\sum((x_i)_p-(x_i)_q)^2}$) to define distance of two points $p, q$ on the intersection, their distance should be non-zero, right? So by saying 'the two points at the self intersection would have distance 0' you mean you use non-Euclidean metric? I see this way we can find an open neighborhood of p. And why we can't allow the distance to be $0$?

Comment: Suppose you have any immersion, you will necessarily have a double point at the intersection right (even a triple point for some immersions)? In $\mathbb{R}^3$ this means that the distance between the two points in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ that map to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $0$. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question? I'm assuming you're trying to use the ambient metric in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to define a metric on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ by just taking the distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$.